# How to create a variable from CSS class attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a variable to is defined by a single attribute of a CSS class.  Here's what I have now, which doesn't work.

```
var dist = $('.nav').css(width());
```

What I am trying to do:  my script slides the .nav class upon click.  The problem is, I'm using @media queries that change the width of .nav, which is the same value I need to slide.  What I'm trying to do here is define the variable "dist" by the width attribute of .nav - then I could just input "dist" as the slide distance in the function.

This is probably a pretty simple thing that I'm just doing horribly wrong.  Or perhaps there is a far simpler way to do it?

Comment: `.css('width')` or just `.width()`

Comment: downvoted for writing "any help is appreciated"...  what a douche

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `width` as though it were a function and then (if that worked) passing its return value into `css`. But unless your page defines one, there's no free-standing `width()` function (there *is* one on jQuery instances).

You either want to pass the *string* `"width"` into [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css), or call the jQuery [`width`](http://api.jquery.com/width) function:

```
var dist = $('.nav').css("width");
// or
var dist = $('.nav').width();
```

Comment: cool that works.  guess that's just a beginners mistake on my part.  thanks